# Unable to resolve `Bad file descriptor` from django logging

Tags: python, django, sockets, logging

I'm trying to add Papertrail logging to a Django app, which is build alongside an older Falcon app. Due to some of the v1 to v2 transition, this is how it's setup (a lot of code removed for simplicity):

```
import logging
import logging.config

logger = logging.getLogger('api')

...

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'logstash': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logstash.TCPLogstashHandler',
            'host': LOGSTASH_HOST,
            'port': LOGSTASH_PORT,
            'version': 1,
            'message_type': 'django',
            'fqdn': True,
        },
        {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'address': ('logs.papertrailapp.com', int(CREDENTIALS_PAPERTRAIL_ADDRESS))
        }
    }
    'loggers': {
        'api': {
            'handlers': ['console','SysLog'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
        "gunicorn.error": {
            'handlers': ['console','SysLog'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
        "gunicorn.access": { 
            'handlers': ['console','SysLog'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'access_logs': {
            'handlers': ['logstash'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
})
```

The gunicorn stuff comes from https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2016

In a test file, I have `logger.warning('test asdf')`, which I see get spit out to the console, however, it also throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/handlers.py", line 940, in emit
    self.socket.sendto(msg, self.address)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Thing is, the access logs stuff works; we're seeing that stuff go to logstash, but I cannot seem to figure out this socket issue for papertrail. The format comes straight from their docs too.

Comment: make sure syslog is running